# Designing (properties in) classes for Entity Framework relationships - code first C#

Tags: entity-framework

I'm doing code first Entity Framework in C# and I am short this one area - how to create properties for relationships between the classes.

A simple example: a Video (Id, Name, Release Date) class and a Genre (name & ID) class.

I already have the solution to the above (ICollection in Genre and  public virtual in Video) but in general how can I determine the property I should put in each class for 1:1, 1:Many, Many:Many relationships ? Is there a kind of a template I could check against ?

Comment: Template - I don't think so. You can read [this series](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts) which explain most of the EF relationship modelling concepts.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help.  The tables are very quick to design and so are the relationships but figuring out the mappings and the property type lost me a bit.